# Using sed or awk, how can I alter the first field in a delimited line?

Tags: sed, awk, csv

I have a delimited file whose first few fields look like this:

```
2774013300|184500|2012-01-04 23:00:00|
```

and I want to alter certain rows whose first field equals or exceeds 8 characters. 
I want to truncate the value in the first column.

In the case of `2774013300` I want its value to become become `27740133`.

I would like to do this in `sed`, preferably, or `awk`.

Using `sed`, I can find any number that exceeds 8 digits at the beginning of the line, but am not quite sure how to truncate it, using, I would assume, substitute.

```
sed -n -e /'^[0-9]\{10,\}/p' infile
```

I am thinking I could use grouping for the first 8 characters and return those in a substitute command, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

In awk, I can detect the first field, but am not quite sure how to use substr to alter the first field and then return the remaining fields, so a full line is preserved.

```
awk -F'|'  '{ if (length($1) > 9) { print $1; print length($1);} }' infile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the subtleties of your situation, you can use

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{8\}\)[0-9]*/\1/' infile
```

or

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{8\}\)[0-9]\{1,\}/\1/' infile
```

which with GNU sed can be simplified to

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{8})[0-9]+/\1/' infile
```

or, if you need to, add `-n` and `p`.

Example:

```
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]\{8\}\)[0-9]*/\1/' <<<'2774013300|184500|2012-01-04 23:00:00|'
27740133|184500|2012-01-04 23:00:00|
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll go try this. I see what you're doing now, grouping the first 8 and the possible last two, right? And the last two should go blank if there are only 8 characters?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus You said "alter certain rows whose first field equals or exceeds 10 characters", so this will match only if there are at least 10 digits, and remove everything after the 8th one. If you actually want to alter everything that is 8 or longer, then please edit the question, and I'll edit the answer by changing `\{2,\}` to just `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}length($1)>9{$1=substr($1, 0,9)}{print}'
```

example:

```
$ echo "2774013300|184500|2012-01-04 23:00:00|" | awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}length($1)>9{$1=substr($1, 0,9)}{print}'
27740133|184500|2012-01-04 23:00:00|
```

Comment: Thanks for the awk example. I had something much more unnecessarily complicated.